# Convergence in Distribution of CDF but not PDF

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I came across this example that demonstrates the convergence of the CDF of a random variable converging in distribution but not the convergence of the PDF.

I just have two questions:

1. Why is the PDF for $X_{n}$ have the $\frac{1}{n}$ term while the PDF for X alone does not? And likewise, why does the CDF for $F_{n}(x)$ have the $\frac{1}{n}$ term while the CDF for F(x) does not.
2. How are they deriving the CDF from the PDF? If you integrate the constants don't you get x?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure you are asking a right question. Your $X_n$ in the counter example is a discrete r.v., which doesn't have a PDF (probability density function)

Comment: @YanZhu Oh true. Is there a simple example in the continuous case counterexample that you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_n$ is a point mass at $1+\frac1n$, while $X$ is a point mass at $1$. That's why there is a $\frac1n$ in one case but not the other. Since these are discrete random variables, you perform summation instead of integration to get the CDF. And the CDF of a point mass at $x=a$ is the function
$$
F(x):=P(X\le x)=\begin{cases} 0&\text{ if $x<a$}\\1&\text{ if $x\ge a$}\end{cases}
$$
Argue by cases, as follows: If $x<a$, then it is impossible for $X\le x$, so $P(X\le x)=0$. If $x\ge a$, then the event $\{X\le x\}$ is the event $\{X=a\}$, which has probability $1$.